# What is the difference between Sapphire Radeon R9 270X 4GB GDDR5 and Sapphire Radeon R9 270X 2GB GDDR5

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Well i am considering to buy a new Graphics Card
What is a difference between 4Gb graphic card and 2GB graphic card?
Is there a big difference? 
And if its compatible with my PC (Asus p7p55d motherboard) i5 processor with 18 Giga RAM )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twice the memory which is used for texture storage and more, hence 2gb vs 4gb.  If you play games on high or ultra quality settings they will use all of it.  If you run out your game may slow down to compensate. Also all the new games are using more.  AMD is even releasing the r9 290x with 6gb.